Selenium not scraping images when running python script
I'm trying to scrape a website for images via selenium python. I'v e made references to the file location and there are no errors when the script is run. But the folder remains empty. Is this because more waits need to be implemented? Or the file locations specified are somewhat incorrect?
import hashlib
import io
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(
"https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/bn_79257191?_trkparms=parentrq%3A17b9fd4e1910aaf4d205ce64ffff9878%7Cpageci%3Ae4c4c85d"
"-5180-11ef-874e-06e2120eee8d%7Cc%3A1%7Ciid%3A2%7Cli%3A8874")
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.quit()


def gets_url(classes, location, source):
results = []
for a in soup.findAll(attrs={"class": classes}):
    name = a.find(location)
    if name not in results:
        results.append(name.get(source))
return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
returned_results = gets_url("s-item__image-wrapper image-treatment", "img", "src")
for b in returned_results:
    image_content = requests.get(b).content
    image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
    image = Image.open(image_file).convert("RGB")
    file_path = Path("/home/kali/Documents/Scripts/my_scripts/Scrape/",
                     hashlib.sha1(image_content).hexdigest()[:10] + ".png")
    image.save("/home/kali/Documents/Images/", "PNG", quality=80)

This is my first time doing any web scraping and I'm still very much a beginner in Python. So any help with this would be greatly appreciated!
I'm aiming to be able to scrape websites for images. I just grabbed a random ebay link to start with. But alas it is not working

The first step in debugging this problem is to check if returned_results actually has any items in it.

Welcome to webscraping. To use soup.findAll() on a class you have to proceed as it follow according to the documentation of bs4:

soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,


According to your project, you are seeking to find all img-url of Ebay product. The class selector in your script s-item__image-wrapper image-treatment is wrong.
The picture is identified by the class s-item__image-img (see below), thanks to inspect element :
<img class="s-item__image-img" alt="Adidas Originals Mens Trainers Handball Spezial Leather Lace Up blue UK Size" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/BXcAAOSwWbNkZNV7/s-l960.webp">

To find all element related to the tag img and the class s-item__image-img:
data = soup.findAll("img", class_="s-item__image-img")
print(data) # [<img alt="Adidas Originals Mens Trainers Handball Spezial Leather Lace Up blue UK Size" class="s-item__image-img" src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/BXcAAOSwWbNkZNV7/s-l960.webp"/>, ...]

To return only pictures of Ebay products you need to iterate throught element["src"] :
for e in data:
    url = e['src']
    print(url) # https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/ioEAAOSwrc5mfBSi/s- 
    # https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/4hoAAOSwmmlmolpp/s-l960.webp
    # https://ir.ebaystatic.com/cr/v/c1/s_1x2.gif

As you see, an unwanted .gif file is return. Why ?
Because if you look at the result of data you'll see thing like that :
img alt="ADIDAS REVERSIBLE WEBBING BELT NAVY / GREY **2024 CLEARANCE**" class="s-item__image-img" data-high-res-src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/MtAAAOSwp0hmdDfX/s-l960.webp" data-src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/MtAAAOSwp0hmdDfX/s-l300.webp" src="https://ir.ebaystatic.com/cr/v/c1/s_1x2.gif"/

If you look closly you'll see that src content is a gif file and the image.webp you are looking for is in data-src content.
You should now use condition to check if url variable endswith .webp or .gif then look for data-src instead of src :
data = soup.findAll("img", class_="s-item__image-img")

for url in soup:
    if data['src'].endswith(".webp"):
        print(data['src'])
    elif data['src'].endswith(".gif"):
        print(data['data-src'])

And... That's all ! Adjust your script with your new knowledge and you'll be done. Feel free to upvote and tag this issue as resolve if it the case.
